# Time scale separation and cascading control loops

Tags: attitude, flight-control

The typical approach to designing flight control systems is to design an inner control loop to stabilize vehicle attitude and angular rates, while an outer loop tracks vehicle position. The reason given for the above is that attitude dynamics is "faster" than the translational dynamics.

The theory of timescale separation in dynamic systems seems to provide an answer to this question, but what is the physical intuition behind this argument? Also, is it possible to design a controller that does not consist of multiple cascading loops?